# Converting certain index values in list to int

Tags: list, python-3.x

I have searched for a solution to this, but I have not been able to find one, weirdly.

I am opening a file with the following contents in it.

```
Alex,10,0,6,3,7,4
Bob, 6,3,7,2,1,8
```

I want to convert all the values in score_list from 1-4 index value to an integer. I have tried to do so with this following but it just doesn't work.

```
    score_list = []
    def opening_file():
         counter = 0
         with open('scores.txt', newline='') as infile:
             reader = csv.reader(infile)
             for row in reader:
                score_list.append(row[0:5])

             counter = 0
             while counter != 5:
               counter +=1
               row[counter] = int(row[counter])
             print (score_list)

    opening_file()
```

but it doesn't work and just produces

```
[['Alex', '10', '0', '6', '3'], ['Bob', ' 6', '3', '7', '2']]
```

instead of `[['Alex', 10, 0, 6, 3], ['Bob', 6, 3, 7, 2]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` loop transforming the values in `row` happens too late. Each row's values have already been copied (by a slice operation) into a new list which has been appended to `score_list`. And you only run the loop on the last row anyway (assuming your indentation in the question is correct).

Try something like this:

```
with open('scores.txt', newline='') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        for i in range(1,5):
            row[i] = int(row[i])
        score_list.append(row[0:5])
```

I'm using a `for` loop on a range, rather than a `while` loop, just because it's more convenient (a `while` loop version could work just fine, it just requires more lines). The key thing is to change `row` inside the loop on `reader` and before we slice the row to `append` to `score_list`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I found all the answers helpful but I found this one in particular because you did remember to add in the code that only appends row[0:5].

Answer (score 2):

You are converting the items within `row` which is just a throwaway variable. Also you don't need to that redundant works, you can simply unpack your row to `name` and `scores` parts and use a list comprehension in order to convert the digits to integer.

```
with open('scores.txt', newline='') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        name, *scores = row
        score_list.append([name] + [int(i) for i in scores])
```

Comment: I think you cannot concatenate arbitrary iterables to a list

Comment: @TamasHegedus Sorry I didn't got you. What you mean by *arbitrary iterables*?

Comment: I mean a python 3.x `map` object: `[name]+map(int, scores)`

Comment: @TamasHegedus Yeah, Indeed. Thanks for reminding that I just changed it.

Comment: I like the use of the extended unpacking here, +1

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the code converts items in the `row` array, but you print the `score_list` array. Second, as it alters the `row` variable outside the reader for loop, it only alters the last row. You could do something like this:

```
import csv

def opening_file():
  with open('scores.txt', newline='') as infile:
    return [[row[0]] + [int(x) for x in row[1:]] for row in csv.reader(infile)]
score_list = opening_file()
print(str(score_list))
```